# How to apply something to an element but not its children, in an Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, jqlite

In my Angular project, I have a recursive template that creates a series of "blocks" (each consisting of an encompassing `div` with other elements inside it) nested a few levels deep - similar to this one:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplate.html">
     <div drop-target='true' class="overall">         
          <h2> {{obj.title}} </h2>
          <div> {{obj.content}} </div>
          <div ng-include="'myTemplate.html'" onload="obj=someObject.innerObjects"></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Each of these `overall` divs has a directive that lets it accept items that are dragged into it (standard drag and drop).

The problem is, that the dropping is also being allowed to happen onto the `<h2>` element and the content `div`. This is not what I want. I want the dropping to only be over the `overall` div.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Are you using jquery ui draggable. If yes then you can specify the element to disable the drag on cancel attributes. Some thing like this :element.draggable({
                containment: '.something',
                cursor: 'move',
                cancel: '.disable',
                revert: 'invalid',
                snap: 'true',
                stop: function (event, ui) {

                }
            }); Then add 2 ".disable" class to your <h2> and <div>{{obj.content}}</div>. Hope it helps